# Using `mutate` to create column copies using a named vector

Tags: r, dplyr, names

I have a `tibble` and a named vector. I would like to make *copies* of all of the columns in my named vector using the vector names while preserving the original names.

I know how to rename all the columns fairly simply:

```r
library(dplyr)

named_vector <- 
  c("var1" = "x1",
    "var2" = "x2",
    "var3" = "x3")

tibble(x1 = 1:3, x2 = 1:3, x3 = 1:3, z = 68, zz = 69) %>% 
  rename(!!!named_vector)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>    var1  var2  var3     z    zz
#>   <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     1     1    68    69
#> 2     2     2     2    68    69
#> 3     3     3     3    68    69
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

But I don't know how to do the equivalent using `mutate`. How can I make copies of the columns in a way that preserves the original names and but also has the vector names?

My expected output would be the equivalent of:

```r
library(dplyr)

named_vector <- 
  c("var1" = "x1",
    "var2" = "x2",
    "var3" = "x3")

tibble(x1 = 1:3, x2 = 1:3, x3 = 1:3, z = 68, zz = 69) %>% 
  mutate(var1 = x1,
         var2 = x2,
         var3 = x3)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 8
#>      x1    x2    x3     z    zz  var1  var2  var3
#>   <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1     1     1     1    68    69     1     1     1
#> 2     2     2     2    68    69     2     2     2
#> 3     3     3     3    68    69     3     3     3
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may use `across` with `mutate`, and rename with `str_replace` by replacing the substring 'x' with 'var' to create new columns

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
tibble(x1 = 1:3, x2 = 1:3, x3 = 1:3) %>%
    mutate(across(everything(), 
       .names = "{str_replace(.col, 'x', 'var')}"))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 6
     x1    x2    x3  var1  var2  var3
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1     1     1     1     1     1
2     2     2     2     2     2     2
3     3     3     3     3     3     3
```

---

Or use `match` to named_vector in `.names`

```
tibble(x1 = 1:3, x2 = 1:3, x3 = 1:3) %>% 
    mutate(across(all_of(unname(named_vector)),
      .names = "{names(named_vector)[match(.col, named_vector)]}"))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 6
     x1    x2    x3  var1  var2  var3
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1     1     1     1     1     1
2     2     2     2     2     2     2
3     3     3     3     3     3     3
```

---

With the updated post also the solution works

```
tibble(x1 = 1:3, x2 = 1:3, x3 = 1:3, z = 68, zz = 69)  %>%  
    mutate(across(all_of(unname(named_vector)),
       .names = "{names(named_vector)[match(.col, named_vector)]}"))
# A tibble: 3 x 8
     x1    x2    x3     z    zz  var1  var2  var3
  <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int> <int>
1     1     1     1    68    69     1     1     1
2     2     2     2    68    69     2     2     2
3     3     3     3    68    69     3     3     3
```

Comment: This second solution is very close, but I see it doesn't work when there are more columns than x1:x3

Comment: I added two more columns to the example that will cause this to create an error

Answer (score 2):

You can create new columns from existing columns using -

```
data <- tibble::tibble(x1 = 1:3, x2 = 1:3, x3 = 1:3, z = 68, zz = 69)
data[names(named_vector)] <- data[named_vector]
data

#     x1    x2    x3     z    zz  var1  var2  var3
#  <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int> <int>
#1     1     1     1    68    69     1     1     1
#2     2     2     2    68    69     2     2     2
#3     3     3     3    68    69     3     3     3
```

Answer (score 2):

The new variable names will be taken from the named vector just by doing:

```
library(dplyr)

tibble(x1 = 1:3, x2 = 4:6, x3 = 7:9, z = 68, zz = 69) %>% 
   mutate(across(all_of(named_vector)))

# A tibble: 3 x 8
     x1    x2    x3     z    zz  var1  var2  var3
  <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int> <int>
1     1     1     1    68    69     1     1     1
2     2     2     2    68    69     2     2     2
3     3     3     3    68    69     3     3     3
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use `rename_with` from `dplyr` package after `cbind`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    cbind(df[,1:3]) %>% 
    rename_with(.cols = 6:8, ~ names(named_vector), .name_repair = c("minimal"))
```

output:

```
 x1 x2 x3  z zz var1 var2 var3
1  1  1  1 68 69    1    1    1
2  2  2  2 68 69    2    2    2
3  3  3  3 68 69    3    3    3
```

Answer (score 2):

Although there are already a lot of answers, there is one more important way to do this kind of programming with {dplyr}. `mutate` can evaluate list of expressions. So instead of providing a `named_vector` we can create a named list of expressions `exp_ls`.

```r
library(dplyr)
exp_ls <- list("var1" = expr(x1),
               "var2" = expr(x2),
               "var3" = expr(x3))

tibble(x1 = 1:3, x2 = 1:3, x3 = 1:3, z = 68, zz = 69) %>% 
  mutate(!!! exp_ls)

#> # A tibble: 3 x 8
#>      x1    x2    x3     z    zz  var1  var2  var3
#>   <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1     1     1     1    68    69     1     1     1
#> 2     2     2     2    68    69     2     2     2
#> 3     3     3     3    68    69     3     3     3
```

We can also easily transform the given `named_vector` to a list of expressions using `syms(named_vector)`:<sup>*</sup>

```
named_vector <- 
  c("var1" = "x1",
    "var2" = "x2",
    "var3" = "x3")

tibble(x1 = 1:3, x2 = 1:3, x3 = 1:3, z = 68, zz = 69) %>% 
  mutate(!!! syms(named_vector)

#> # A tibble: 3 x 8
#>      x1    x2    x3     z    zz  var1  var2  var3
#>   <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1     1     1     1    68    69     1     1     1
#> 2     2     2     2    68    69     2     2     2
#> 3     3     3     3    68    69     3     3     3
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>
<sup>*</sup> Thanks to @`27 ϕ 9` who suggested `syms` instead of `sapply(named_vector, str2lang)`.

Comment: Nice! Totally forgot that we can use `syms` here with the intended behavior. I added it to my answer.